# Дополнительные breakpoint в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте, не подскажите, как в bootstrap 3 добавить дополнительные breakpoint для media запросов. Точка перелома "менее 768px" явно недостаточна.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ - здесь нет того, что вам нужно?

Comment: @Byulent здесь есть, но я ничего не понял, так как без примеров. Там говорится, что изменять можно через less переменные. Но во-первых, мне непонятно, можно ли это делать в рамках  стандартного пакета установки Bootstrap 3 (или нужна установка с папкой less). Во-вторых, непонятно какие классы надо добавлять в качестве примесей. Предполагаю, скажем,  что можно создать .col-sx-min-* ,  затем добавить в качестве примеси туда col-xs-* и переопределить максимальный размер экрана. Но хотелось бы узнать правильный вариант...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [решение на SASS](https://gist.github.com/Jakobud/c057577daddbde4dd709).

Но часто от нового брекпоинта требуется только одно — растянуть колонки на весь экран, когда страницу смотрят с вертикально ориентированного смартфона.

В таких случаях вместо полноценного набора новых классов достаточно одной инструкции:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  [class|="col-xs"] {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

В примере ниже поставил брекпоинт на 650 пикселей, чтобы он срабатывал в окошке сниппета.

```css
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  [class|="col-xs"] {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

/* Decorations */
.container.decorations {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
.container.decorations .row > div {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 1px;
  min-height: 45px;
  padding-top: 6px;
}
.container.decorations .row>div:nth-of-type(3n) {
  background: #9c6;
}
.container.decorations .row>div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  background: #f93;
}
.container.decorations .row>div:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  background: #69c;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container decorations">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">.col-xs-2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">.col-xs-3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">.col-xs-5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">.col-xs-7</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">.col-xs-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">.col-xs-9</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">.col-xs-10</div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">.col-xs-11</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">.col-xs-12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да красивое решение для экономии времени. Этого одного breakpointa в большинстве случаев будет достаточно. Тему пока не закрываю, может кто покажет, как тоже самое делается на less.

Comment: @НиколайВанин Вот [решение на SASS](https://gist.github.com/Jakobud/c057577daddbde4dd709). Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться. Закрываю тему.

Answer (score 1):

Решение кажется оказалось более легким, чем предполагал. Требуется простая правка bootstrap.css. 
1) В список классов колонок добавляется класс с произвольным названием (например col-exs-1) плюс его остальные 11 вариантов:

```
.col-exs-1, .col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-exs-2, .col-xs-
2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-exs-3, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-
md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-exs-4,  .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, 
.col-exs-5, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-exs-6, .col-xs-
6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-exs-7, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-
md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-exs-8, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, 
.col-exs-9, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-exs-10, .col-
xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-exs-11, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-
11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-exs-12, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, 
.col-lg-12 {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```

2) параметры css, относящиеся к самым "маленьким" классам col-xs-* убрать в медиазапрос: @media (min-width:450px){}
3) эти же самые параметры скопировать и вставить до медиазапроса, 
изменив col-xs-* на col-exs-*. Их убирать в медиазапрос не надо.

```
.col-exs-1, .col-exs-2, .col-exs-3, .col-exs-4, .col-exs-5, .col-exs-6, 
.col-exs-7, .col-exs-8, .col-exs-9, .col-exs-10, .col-exs-11, .col-exs-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-exs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-exs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
 .col-exs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-exs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-exs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-1 {
 width: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-pull-12 {
  right: 100%;
}
.col-exs-pull-11 {
  right: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-pull-10 {
  right: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-pull-9 {
  right: 75%;
}
.col-exs-pull-8 {
  right: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-pull-7 {
  right: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-pull-6 {
  right: 50%;
}
.col-exs-pull-5 {
  right: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-pull-4 {
  right: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-pull-3 {
  right: 25%;
}
.col-exs-pull-2 {
  right: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-pull-1 {
  right: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-pull-0 {
  right: auto;
}
.col-exs-push-12 {
  left: 100%;
}
.col-exs-push-11 {
  left: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-push-10 {
  left: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-push-9 {
  left: 75%;
}
.col-exs-push-8 {
  left: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-push-7 {
  left: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-push-6 {
  left: 50%;
}
.col-exs-push-5 {
  left: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-push-4 {
  left: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-push-3 {
  left: 25%;
}
.col-exs-push-2 {
  left: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-push-1 {
  left: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-push-0 {
  left: auto;
}
.col-exs-offset-12 {
 margin-left: 100%;
}
.col-exs-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}
.col-exs-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.col-exs-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.col-exs-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-exs-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-exs-offset-0 {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

В итоге появится новая точка восстановления с экраном менее 450px.

Comment: Да, но лучше не править bootstrap.css, а подцепить к странице собственный файл стилей, в который складывать все свои дополнения. Так будет легче и обновлять бутстрап, и вспоминать, что именно к нему добавляли.

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky Спасибо. Полезное замечание, сразу не пришло на ум. Найти и редактировать правки тогда будет гораздо  легче. И не надо потом минимизировать bootstrap.css.